# GTA V disc 1 download

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I just got a copy of GTA V but only disc 2. My brother doesn't have the game right now but he has disc 1 (install disc) on his HDD. I know I can transfer it to a flash drive but is there a way to copy it so it's still on his HDD and the flash?

Comment: Even if you do this unless your brother purchased the digital copy of GTA5 he will need the GTA5 Disk 2.

Comment: He owns the game, both discs, he just doesn't have them right now because he let someone borrow the game. Sorry, I just realized that was confusing.

Comment: He won't be able to play the game without the non-instal GTA5 disk.

Comment: He owns both discs. He just doesn't have them right now. I only have disc 2. We both have disc 2 (noninstall), I was just trying to copy his download of disc 1 (install). I did it, it worked fine, thanks user68765, I feel kinda stupid I didn't figure that out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes hit Y after hovering over the install and select copy then select your memory stick.